# Как переместить запятую

Tags: java, android

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(convert("5"));
        System.out.println(convert("56"));
        System.out.println(convert("560"));
        System.out.println(convert("5600"));
    }

    public static double convert(String str){
        double asd=Double.valueOf(str);
        return asd/100;
    }
```

---

```
0.05
0.56
5.6
56.0
```

Все работает кроме 2 последних чисел.
Проблема в том что должно быть 5.60 и 56.00.
А мы имеем 5.6 и 56.0

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Освойте `String.format` и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Немного теории:**

Для того чтобы вернуть данные, вам необходимо отформатировать их. Для этого можно использовать метод *.format()* из класса *String*, который вернет  отформатированные данные в качестве строки.

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args)
```

- *String format* - это строка, определяет шаблон, согласно которому будет происходить форматирование.
- *Object... args* - это аргументы, на которые ссылаются спецификаторы формата в строке формата. Если аргументов больше, чем спецификаторов формата, дополнительные аргументы игнорируются. Число аргументов является переменной и может быть нулевым. Максимальное количество аргументов ограничено максимальным размером массива Java, как определено Спецификацией виртуальной машины Java ™. Поведение на нулевом аргументе зависит от преобразования.

Взято из [офф. документации Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Согласно заданному нами шаблону мы берем аргумент под номером `%1$` и говорим что нужно вывести `.2f`- два знака после запятой.

**Решение:**

Измените свою функцию Convert следующим образом:

```
    public String convert(String str) {
        double myDouble = Double.valueOf(str) / 100;
        return String.format("%1$,.2f", myDouble);
    }
```

Надеюсь мой ответ помог вам.

Comment: Спасибо работает. Могли бы вы объяснить что это и как это рабоает?

Comment: @Andro поправил ответ, если есть еще вопросы, постараюсь помочь